# Wordpress wp-api Get Users By Username

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api

I have just installed this plugin into our WP site and am trying to figure out how to property use the [users](http://wp-api.org/#users_retrieve-users_input) endpoint to find a user by their username.  I have tried the filter several different ways, but it keeps returning all users.  Has anyone been able to accomplish this, and if so, what parameters need to be passed to properly setup the filter?

Here is the URL I am using
`http://www.example.com/wp-json/users?filter[orderby]=login&filter[s]=admin`

I have tried it with and without the `orderby` parameter, which according to the docs, is supposed to determine what field the filter applies to.  I have also tried setting the value of the orderbvy user_login.

Comment: The reason I was doing this was to check if the user existed before creating it.  However, it looks like the create user returns some json saying it already existed, so I think that will work for now.  I would still like to know why this is not working in case I need it for something different in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the search [argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#arguments)

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?search=myusername
```

Comment: This worked for me, not the above using the parameter ```username```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, so I have created extension plugin https://github.com/dest81/wp-api-get-user-by-username

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by username directly:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?username=jsmith
```

[WP REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#schema)

Comment: this does not seem to work, it just retrieves all users